# Merge two Methods into Single Generic Method

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I've two methods in my DAL which are identical and return a database row based on the primary key suppied as a parameter.  The DB context is linqtoSQL.   One passes in a string parameter and the second passes in an int parameter. I think there must be away to use generics to create a single method which accepts string or int but not sure how.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Select table row by integer Primary Key Value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="id">The PK value to search for</param>
    /// <returns>Single matching PK to id</returns>
    public T SelectRowByPk<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        using (var dc = new DBDataContext())
        {
            // Get the table by the type passed in
            var table = dc.GetTable<T>();
            // Get the metamodel mappings (database to domain objects)
            MetaModel modelMap = table.Context.Mapping;
            // Get the data members for this type
            ReadOnlyCollection<MetaDataMember> dataMembers =  
            modelMap.GetMetaType(typeof (T)).DataMembers;
            // Find the primary key field name by checking for IsPrimaryKey
            string pk = (dataMembers.Single(m => m.IsPrimaryKey)).Name;

            // Return a single object where the id argument matches the primary key 
            field value
            return table.SingleOrDefault(delegate(T t)
                                            {
                                                int memberId =

  Convert.ToInt16(t.GetType().GetProperty(pk).GetValue(t, null));
                                                return memberId == id;
                                            });
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Select table row by Varchar Primary Key Value
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="id">The PK value to search for</param>
    /// <returns>Single matching PK to id</returns>
    public T SelectRowByVarcharPk<T>(string id) where T : class
    {
        using (var dc = new DBDataContext())
        {
            // Get the table by the type passed in
            var table = dc.GetTable<T>();
            // Get the metamodel mappings (database to domain objects)
            MetaModel modelMap = table.Context.Mapping;
            // Get the data members for this type
            ReadOnlyCollection<MetaDataMember> dataMembers = 
  modelMap.GetMetaType(typeof(T)).DataMembers;
            // Find the primary key field name by checking for IsPrimaryKey
            string pk = (dataMembers.Single(m => m.IsPrimaryKey)).Name;

            // Return a single object where the id argument matches the primary key 
 field value
            return table.SingleOrDefault(delegate(T t)
            {
                string memberId =
                   t.GetType().GetProperty(pk).GetValue(t, null).ToString();
                return memberId == id;
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use generics directly to combine two methods into one, however you can use a little refactoring in combination with generics to have a clean design:

Make a private method that does the heavy lifting with two generic parameters, one for entity type and on for primary key type:

```
 private T SelectRowById<T, TId>(TId id) where T : class
    {
        using (var dc = new DBDataContext())
        {
            // Get the table by the type passed in
            var table = dc.GetTable<T>();
            // Get the metamodel mappings (database to domain objects)
            MetaModel modelMap = table.Context.Mapping;
            // Get the data members for this type
            ReadOnlyCollection<MetaDataMember> dataMembers = 
  modelMap.GetMetaType(typeof(T)).DataMembers;
            // Find the primary key field name by checking for IsPrimaryKey
            string pk = (dataMembers.Single(m => m.IsPrimaryKey)).Name;

            // Return a single object where the id argument matches the primary key 
 field value
            return table.SingleOrDefault(delegate(T t)
            {
                var memberId =
                   (TId)t.GetType().GetProperty(pk).GetValue(t, null);
                return memberId == id;
            });
        }
    }
```

After this you can declare two public methods for specific id type that use this private method:

```
public T SelectRowById<T>(string id) where T : class
{
   return SelectRowById<T, string>(id);
}

public T SelectRowById<T>(int id) where T : class
{
   return SelectRowById<T, int>(id);
}
```

This way you will have a clean public interface with minimum code duplication.

Answer (score -1):

```
public T SelectRowByPk<T>(T id)
{
    //you'll need to do some run-time type checking of 'id' here since string and int
    //can't be constrained by a type parameter constraint in the same method
}
```

One of the points of specifying a type parameter is so that one can have dynamic parameter types. In this example, 'id' becomes whatever type you specify.